# How to find orthogonal distance between epipolar line and feature points?

Tags: c, opencv, visual-c++

How to find orthogonal distance between epipolar line and feature points? Feature point can a point that is taken for tracking in next consecutive frames like harris corner etc. is I'm using opencv c++ . please help me or give some good reference. Thanks

Comment: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/

Comment: thanks a lot Martin Beckett sir.. i'll try this link